# excel or excel VBA: how can I let user click on a cell and use it as a match result to an existing cell

Tags: vba, excel, user-input, matching

[Wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CefBC.png)

Attached is a snip picture of what I want to do. I have one column that lists all the options, and on the second column some items. For each item I want the user to physically select a cell and I can then use that selection as the match to the item. For example if the use click on "user1" then I need to populate cell D4 with text "user1". How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the code for the worksheet from which you want to use the selection:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Dim s As String
        s = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)
        Sheets("SHEETNAME").Range("D4") = s
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can I let the user drag the cell they want to match all the way over to the destination, i.e. D4?

Comment: That functionality is actually built directly into excel. You hover your mouse over the border of the cell until a cross with arrows appears, then click and drag the cell to the desired location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a worksheet event handler. Depending on your precise conditions, use either SelectionChange or DoubleClick.

For example, in the worksheet code module:

[image]

This code looks for a user to select a cell in column 1, then updates D4 with the selection's value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 1 Then
            Range("D4").Value = Target.Text
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Bear in mind that this will also update if the user selects a cell with the keyboard, which is why you may prefer using the before double click event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
```

(You will also need to add Cancel = True to the above code if you use this, or it will allow the users to edit the value in that cell)

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Can I let the user drag the cell they want to match all the way over to the destination, i.e. D4?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. They can click the cell, then click and drag the cell border to move the value to a new range anyway, that is a native feature of excel. Do you want them to be able to do that, but just have it copy the cells? Because if so, you don't need a programming solution, you need to press Ctrl when you do the above.